# Installing ubuntu 13.04 as only os but windows still there (Asus UX32A)?

Tags: installation, windows-8, asus, ssd

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 as my only OS but something goes wrong (I'm not so good at this).

I have Secure Boot disabled, CSM Boot enabled, and cannot find where to disable Intel Smart Response Technology.

Should I choose to put Ubuntu on the small SSD or on the lager disc?

Anyway, in the installation, I chose to install Ubuntu as my only OS on the small SSD.
The installation was successful, or so it said, but when I restarted my computer, there was Windows 8.

I can access Ubuntu via advanced restart from Windows or if I choose to "boot from Ubuntu". I get the grubmenu.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

have you formated the larger disc? or just the ssd? seems you have win8 in the HDD yet. the main reason you should put on the ssd is because the system startup going to be faster.

Comment: Ultrabooks also have nVidia and need nomodeset to boot.   <br />    http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

You said that you have Windows 8 installed, I assume your CPU is a 64Bit and your BIOS a EFI (or UEFI). And to properly install Ubuntu (At its best) it is kind of important.

How to know if CPU is 32bit ou 64bit Click [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-how-to-find-if-processor-is-64-bit-or-not/)

How to know if your BIOS is EFI or LEGACY :
You will have to access your BIOS again and look for EFI (or UEFI), if you can't find it; there are good chances that your BIOS is LEGACY (But I doubt it with Windows 8).
(Personally in my BIOS, it's in the BOOT options).

(There are chances that your booting troubles are because of EFI, did you use an  Ubuntu ISO 32Bits ?)
For more info about that Click [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI).

If your CPU is 64Bits, download an Ubuntu ISO 64.
If your CPU is 32Bits, download an Ubuntu ISO 32.
If your BIOS is EFI (or UEFI), and your CPU a 32Bit (Should not happen I guess), change EFI in your BIOS for LEGACY and download an Ubuntu ISO 32. (Do not care about the word ISO).

............................................

Also, format the partition with Windows on it.

Comment: Now Im even more confused.